# Run length encoding of vectors in MATLAB: looped version and vectorized version

Tags: matlab, compression, vectorization

A project I'm working on requires something akin to run length encoding on a vector in matlab. The data is in the form of a numeric vector, and the output is in the form of two vectors, `elems` and `lens` that hold the elements and their respective run lengths. For example `data = [20 13 12 12 12 18 17 16 16 11]` would give `elems = [20 13 12 18 17 16 11]` and `lens = [1 1 3 1 1 2 1]`. There is no minimum run length.

My first attempt uses loops:

```
clear all

data = [2 1 2 3 3 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 3 3 3 2 1 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 1 1 1];
n = length(data);
elems = zeros(n, 1);
lens = zeros(n, 1);

len = 1;
elem = data(1);
c = 1;
for k = 2:n
    if data(k) == elem
        len = len + 1;
    else
        elems(c) = elem;
        lens(c) = len;
        c = c + 1;
        elem = data(k);
        len = 1;
    end
end

elems(c) = elem;
lens(c) = len;
lens = lens(lens ~= 0);
elems = elems(lens ~= 0);
```

It's pretty basic although I couldn't think of a way to efficiently preallocate the `elems` and `lens` vectors to something smaller than `n`. I figured I could always start them small, e.g. `n/2` or something, keep track of their size, then reallocate them to something larger, maybe 1.5 times the previous size, if they were running out of room, or something like that.

My second attempt is completely vectorized:

```
clear all

data = [2 1 2 3 3 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 3 3 3 2 1 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 1 1 1];
breaks = [true data(2:end) ~= data(1:end-1)];
run_starts = find([breaks true]);
elems_vec = data(breaks);
lens_vec = diff(run_starts);
```

Can either of these methods be improved? The algorithms are pretty simple, and Im really just looking for general feedback that can help me learn matlab a bit more.

Comment: You can replace `data(2:end) ~= data(1:end-1)` with `diff(data)`. Otherwise looks perfect to me, good job! +1

Comment: @Divakar can you clarify what you mean? `diff(data)` is definitely not the same as `data(2:end) ~= data(1:end-1)` when using my example data (just run both in matlab to see that).

Comment: Oh you are right, it's not the same. `diff` is basically difference between consecutive elements and it would work for  your problem too - `breaks = [true ; diff(data)];`

Comment: @Divakar I know what `diff` does, but run `diff(data)` and `data(2:end) ~= data(1:end-1)` on my example data and you can see clearly that you get different results (obviously, because for example, if you have [2 4], `diff` will return 2, but mine will return 1). Can you add an example of what you're talking about? If I make your replacement with `diff` in my second code sample, the code *will fail* because the `elems_vec = data(breaks);` will try to index `data` with a non-logical vector (since `diff` doesn't return 1's and 0's like my code).

Comment: Sorry my bad really, I missed a tiny bit of code. So I meant this - `breaks = [true diff(data)~=0]` and in effect is same as `data(2:end) ~= data(1:end-1)` and thus would result in identical to your results. I am not sure if this is better with performance, which you can find out though. Rest of the code looked perfect to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the performance of my following code however I'm using `tabulate()` to do the job. As you can see, the loops for filtering elements not to compute the frequency of elements. In other words, you might want to look at `tabulate()` or `hist()` to compute the frequent occurrence of elements.

```
x = [20 13 12 12 12 18 17 16 16 11];
j = 1;
elems = []; % store repeated elements
for i = 1:length(x)
    if isempty(find(elems == x(i)))
        elems(j) = x(i);
        j = j + 1;
    end
end
elems
t = tabulate(x); % get frequency table
for i = 1:length(elems)
    lens(i) = t(elems(i),2); % get how many each element in elems vector occurs
end
lens
```

The result is

```
elems =
    20    13    12    18    17    16    11
lens =
     1     1     3     1     1     2     1
```

Comment: I'll look into using `hist()`. I don't want to fork over more money to mathworks just for the statistics toolbox (for `tabulate()`).